# What is sequence file in hadoop?

Tags: file, hadoop, input, mapreduce, sequence

I am new to Map-reduce and I want to understand what is sequence file data input? I studied in the Hadoop book but it was hard for me to understand.

Comment: I guess it would be better if you can put a specific question out of your research.

Comment: The point is that there are many resources about the sequence files in the internet. But I wondered if someone can easily illustrate the structure of sequence file?

Comment: I mean what is exactly the key and the value which we should consider in a sequence file. and what is their differences with a plain text and how is a sequence file looks like?

Comment: [Hadoop Sequence File](http://hadooptutorial.info/hadoop-sequence-files-example/).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First we should understand what problems does the SequenceFile try to solve, and then how can SequenceFile help to solve the problems.

### In HDFS

- SequenceFile is one of the solutions to small file problem in Hadoop.
- Small file is significantly smaller than the HDFS block size(128MB).
- Each file, directory, block in HDFS is represented as object and occupies 150 bytes.
- 10 million files, would use about 3 gigabytes of memory of NameNode.
- A billion files is not feasible.

### In MapReduce

- Map tasks usually process a block of input at a time (using the default FileInputFormat).
- The more the number of files is, the more number of Map task need and the job time can be much more slower.

### Small file scenarios

- The files are pieces of a larger logical file.
- The files are inherently small, for example, images.

**These two cases require different solutions.**

- For first one, write a program to concatenate the small files together.(see Nathan Marz’s [post](https://blog.cloudera.com/the-small-files-problem/) about a tool called the Consolidator which does exactly this)
- For the second one, some kind of container is needed to group the files in some way.

### Solutions in Hadoop

**HAR files**

- HAR([Hadoop Archives](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html)) were introduced to alleviate the problem of lots of files putting pressure on the namenode’s memory.
- HARs are probably best used purely for archival purposes.

**SequenceFile**

- The concept of SequenceFile is to put each small file to a larger single file.
- For example, suppose there are 10,000 100KB files, then we can write a program to put them into a single SequenceFile like below, where you can use filename to be the key and content to be the value.

  [image: SequenceFile File Layout]
  <sub>(source: [csdn.net](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20151213123516719))</sub>
- Some benefits:

  1. A smaller number of memory needed on NameNode. Continue with the 10,000 100KB files example,

     - Before using SequenceFile, 10,000 objects occupy about 4.5MB of RAM in NameNode.
     - After using SequenceFile, 1GB SequenceFile with 8 HDFS blocks, these objects occupy about 3.6KB of RAM in NameNode.
  2. SequenceFile is splittable, so is suitable for MapReduce.
  3. SequenceFile is compression supported.
- Supported Compressions, the file structure depends on the compression type.

  1. Uncompressed
  2. Record-Compressed: Compresses each record as it’s added to the file.
     [image: record_compress_seq]
     <sub>(source: [csdn.net](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20151213182753789))</sub>
  3. Block-Compressed
     [image: 这里写图片描述]
     <sub>(source: [csdn.net](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20151213183017236))</sub>

     - Waits until data reaches block size to compress.
     - Block compression provide better compression ratio than Record compression.
     - Block compression is generally the preferred option when using SequenceFile.
     - **Block here is unrelated to HDFS or filesystem block**.

Comment: You are sure the link works? Sorry, I couldnt open the link.

Comment: The link is dead. Link only answers are considered to be poor answer.

Comment: Best answer JiaMing, Thanks

Comment: This answer is copied from "The Small Files Problem" (2009, Balint Szele, cloudera): https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/ You can find in detail explanations there.