# What is a different between hadoop sequence file with n blocks and n sequence file with one block each?

Tags: hadoop

What is more efficient in hadoop if have a single sequence files with n blocks vs n single files with one block each? And why?

Thanks,

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243134/what-is-sequence-file-in-hadoop/34252006) explains in detail about a sequence file in Hadoop and should give you an idea of when to use it vs. making many files..

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I still confuse about the overhead of the logical file (i.e. sequence file) on top of the blocks. If all the blocks is full with hdfs block size (i.e. 64MB), what is the overhead on namenode?