# Reading binaryFile with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Does any one know how to setup the `

> **streamingContext.fileStream [KeyClass, ValueClass, InputFormatClass] (dataDirectory)**

to actually consume binary files.

- Where can I find all the inputformatClass ? The documentation give no
  links for that. I imagine that the ValueClass is related to the
  inputformatClass somehow.
- In the non-streaming version using the method binaryfiles, I can get
  ByteArrays for each files. Is there a way i can get the same with
  sparkStreaming ? If not where can i find those details. Meaning the
  inputformat supportted and the value class it produces. Finally Can
  one pick any KeyClass, aren't all those element connected ?

If someone clarify the use of the method.

**EDIT1**

I have tried the following:

> val bfiles = ssc.fileStreamBytesWritable, BytesWritable, SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat

However the compiler complain as such:

```
[error] /xxxxxxxxx/src/main/scala/EstimatorStreamingApp.scala:14: type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
[error]  value fileStream: [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean, conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)(implicit evidence$10: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$11: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$12: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and> [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String, filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean)(implicit evidence$7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$8: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)] <and> [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory: String)(implicit evidence$4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K, V)]
[error]   val bfiles = ssc.fileStream[BytesWritable, BytesWritable, SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat]("/xxxxxxxxx/Casalini_streamed")
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) all hadoop input format? if your dataset is in sequence file binary/raw format then try SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat

Comment: @squid I have updated the post, i added code based on your input. Please have a look, i am still have some compiler issue. Although i think i wrote the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Follow link to read about about all [hadoop input formats](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html)

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243134/what-is-sequence-file-in-hadoop) well documented answer about sequence file format.

You are facing the compilation issue because of import missmatch.
[Hadoop Mapred vs mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce)

**E.g.**

Java

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text,BytesWritable> dstream=
        sc.fileStream("/somepath",org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.class,
        org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.class,
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.class);
```

I didn't try in scala but it should be something similar;

```
val dstream = sc.fileStream("/somepath", 
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat] ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to compile.

The compilation problem was in the import. I used

- **import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat**

I replaced it with

- **import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat**

Then it works. However i have no idea why. I don't understand the difference between the two hierarchy. The two files seem to have the same content. So it hard to say. If someone could help clarify that here, i think it would help a lot